# ¿Existe algún componente de VS 2013 o de DevExpress 13.2 que me permita listar ficheros de un directorio para que el usuario los descargue?

Tags: c#, devexpress, visual-studio-2013

Quisiera saber como puedo listar ficheros en un componente visual de asp.net, me explico:
 Mi proyecto cuenta con un repositorio de ficheros en un servidor externo, en dicho repositorio se almacenan ficheros de los usuarios de mi aplicación web implementada en VS 2013 con Web Form. Cada usuario tiene su carpeta de ficheros en el servidor externo. ¿Qué componente usar para que a cada usuario le aparezcan sus ficheros y los pueda descargar?
Me seria de gran ayuda....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En DevExpress tienes el control FileManager que te permite hacerlo no sólo con repositorios del sistema de archivos, también con repositorios alojados en Amazon, Azure o Dropbox:

[ASPxFileManager Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9030)

Comment: Muchas Gracias creo q con elcomponente ASPxFileManager resolvi mi rpoblema.... muchas, pero muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien recuerdo no hay un control para ello ya que es una funcionalidad bastante especifica y poco reutilizaban, podrías construir un control propio o quizás usar un Treeview para mostrar los archivos según https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms171645(v=vs.110).aspx